# How to increase accuracy of floating-point values?

Tags: c, floating-point

I am writing a programm that operates on base-4 numbers. How can I make values more accurate?

I have a number 0.668  in decimal which I convert to base-4. It is should be 0.222300 but it is stored as 0.222299, which gives very inaccurate results as it supposed to be a base-4 number. I have read about floating-point arithmetic, but I could not find a way to improve accuracy of numbers in c language. I have treid to use long double, but I could not find a way to print long double values. 
I do not know if it is important, but I use codeblocks with mingw.

Edit:
@EricPostpischil has answered my question.

Comment: Are you using `double`?  You should usually use `double` unless you *really* care about space and *really* don't care about precision.  Other than that, some machines support a `long double` data type, although this will be less portable.

Comment: If you have no performances constraints, there are multiprecision libraries like gmp. Besides that, the compiler relies on the underlying hardware that is supposed to be IEEE754 compliant. Surprised  though of your precision. Should be more accurate than that with a double.

Comment: Oh, to print a `long double` with `printf`, try using `%Lf` (capital L).

Comment: @TomKarzes I have treid %Lf and %Lg,  %LG,  %Le,  %llf. They do not work. I get this warning 'unknown conversion type character 'L' in format'.

Comment: How is 0.222299 base-4??

Comment: Base-4 `0.2223` is not decimal `0.668`. It is `0.66796875` in decimal. I don't think decimal `0.668` *can* be exactly stored in base 4.

Comment: @Aleksander If you want help, you need to post the code where you convert from base-10 to base-4

Comment: @Aleksander It sounds like your stdio library might not support `long double`.  Try using the GNU tool chain (`gcc`, `glibc`, etc.)

Comment: How it is stored is not important. It is always stored "base 2". How it is displayed is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you are trying to use a “decimal encoded base-4” format. That is, given a base-4 numeral (.222300<sub>4</sub>), you reinterpret it as a decimal numeral (.222300<sub>10</sub>), then store the numerical value of the decimal numeral in a `float` or a `double`. Then, because the C implementation you are using uses a binary-based `float` or `double`, you end up with a binary representation, which of course introduces error when converted from the value of a decimal numeral. The primary solution for this is: **Do not do that.** There is no reason to use decimal.

Since you have base-4 numbers, just stick the base-4 digits in some bits. Choose an unsigned integer type and use two of its bits for each base-4 digit. Alternatively, if you must use floating-point, then use two of its bits for each base-4 digit. To represent .222300<sub>4</sub> in `float` or `double`, divide 0 by 4, add 0, divide by 4, add 3, divide by 4, add 2, divide by 4, add 2, divide by 4, add 2, and divide by 4. The result will be exact, and you can then do arithmetic natively in `float` or `double`. Then you just need conversion routines: one for input that converts base-4 numerals to your internal format and one for output that converts your internal format to base-4 numerals.